# How to use tf.case efficiently?

Tags: tensorflow

I want use tf.case to choose different weight in my network, but it is so inefficiency!
For example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from datetime import datetime

tf.reset_default_graph()

M_list = []
time0 = datetime.now()
LENGTH = 100

for i in range(LENGTH):
    M_list.append(tf.get_variable('M'+str(i), shape=[10, 10], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(i)))

with tf.Session() as sess:
    Ma = tf.get_variable('Ma', shape=[10, 1000], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(1))
    choose_mat = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[LENGTH])
    case_set = [(tf.equal(choose_mat[i], 1), lambda i=i: tf.matmul(M_list[i], Ma)) for i in range(LENGTH)]
    Mo = tf.case(case_set)
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    time1 = datetime.now()
    create_time = time1 - time0
    print('create time: ', str(create_time.seconds) + '.' + str(create_time.microseconds).zfill(6))

    for i in range(LENGTH):
        CM = [0] * LENGTH
        CM[i] = 1
        mo = sess.run(Mo, feed_dict={choose_mat: CM})

    time2 = datetime.now()
    run_time = time2 - time1
    total_time = time2 - time0
    print('run time: ', str(run_time.seconds) + '.' + str(run_time.microseconds).zfill(6))
    print('total time: ', str(total_time.seconds) + '.' + str(total_time.microseconds).zfill(6))
```

result:

```
create time:  23.969327
run time:  12.362408
total time:  36.331735
```

I know tf.case will compute all of the branches in case_set.
So I choose weight before compute matmul, like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from datetime import datetime

tf.reset_default_graph()

M_list = []
time0 = datetime.now()
LENGTH = 100

for i in range(LENGTH):
    M_list.append(tf.get_variable('M'+str(i), shape=[10, 10], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(i)))


with tf.Session() as sess:
    choose_mat = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[LENGTH])
    case_set = [(tf.equal(choose_mat[i], 1), lambda i=i: M_list[i]) for i in range(LENGTH)]
    M = tf.case(case_set)

    Ma = tf.get_variable('Ma', shape=[10, 1000], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(1))
    Mo = tf.matmul(M, Ma)
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    time1 = datetime.now()
    create_time = time1 - time0
    print('create time2: ', str(create_time.seconds) + '.' + str(create_time.microseconds).zfill(6))

    for i in range(LENGTH):
        CM = [0] * LENGTH
        CM[i] = 1
        mo = sess.run(Mo, feed_dict={choose_mat: CM})

    time2 = datetime.now()
    create_time = time2 - time1
    total_time = time2 - time0
    print('run time: ', str(create_time.seconds) + '.' + str(create_time.microseconds).zfill(6))
    print('total time: ', str(total_time.seconds) + '.' + str(total_time.microseconds).zfill(6))
```

result:

```
create time2:  23.321199
run time:  5.747378
total time:  29.068577
```

It's faster, seem to have some effect, but it's still slow. If we don't use tf.case, like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from datetime import datetime

tf.reset_default_graph()

M_list = []
time0 = datetime.now()
LENGTH = 100

for i in range(LENGTH):
    M_list.append(tf.get_variable('M'+str(i), shape=[10, 10], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(i)))

with tf.Session() as sess:
    Ma = tf.get_variable('Ma', shape=[10, 1000], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(1))
    choose_mat = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[LENGTH])
    Mo_list = [tf.matmul(M_list[i], Ma) for i in range(LENGTH)]

    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    time1 = datetime.now()
    create_time = time1 - time0
    print('create time: ', str(create_time.seconds) + '.' + str(create_time.microseconds).zfill(6))

    for i in range(LENGTH):
        CM = [0] * LENGTH
        CM[i] = 1
        mo = sess.run(Mo_list[i], feed_dict={choose_mat: CM})

    time2 = datetime.now()
    run_time = time2 - time1
    total_time = time2 - time0
    print('run time: ', str(run_time.seconds) + '.' + str(run_time.microseconds).zfill(6))
    print('total time: ', str(total_time.seconds) + '.' + str(total_time.microseconds).zfill(6))
```

result:

```
create time:  0.547081
run time:  0.596932
total time:  1.144013
```

So the runtime with tf.case is more than ten times of runtime without tf.case!
But I want select weight by tensor, so how to use tf.case efficiently? Or dose any more efficient method exist?

Great thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a efficient method, and DON'T USE tf.case! It's stupid.

This way can select weights by tensor efficiently:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from datetime import datetime

tf.reset_default_graph()

time0 = datetime.now()
LENGTH = 100
M_list = [tf.get_variable('M'+str(i), shape=[10, 10, 1], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(i)) for i in range(LENGTH)]
M_concat = tf.concat(M_list, axis=2, name='M_concat')

with tf.Session() as sess:
    choose_mat = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[1])
    M = M_concat[:, :, choose_mat[0]]
    M = tf.squeeze(M)

    Ma = tf.get_variable('Ma', shape=[10, 1000], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(1))
    Mo = tf.matmul(M, Ma)

    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    time1 = datetime.now()
    create_time = time1 - time0
    print('create time: ', str(create_time.seconds) + '.' + str(create_time.microseconds).zfill(6))

    for i in range(LENGTH):
        mo = sess.run(Mo, feed_dict={choose_mat: [i]})

    time2 = datetime.now()
    create_time = time2 - time1
    total_time = time2 - time0
    print('run time: ', str(create_time.seconds) + '.' + str(create_time.microseconds).zfill(6))
    print('total time: ', str(total_time.seconds) + '.' + str(total_time.microseconds).zfill(6))
```

result:

```
create time:  0.540483
run time:  0.085812
total time:  0.626295
```

I don't know what tf.case is use for since it's so slow. But we do need if or switch to control flow, I think it should have been more efficient.